# How can I print this rectangle shape using c++?

Tags: c++

I tried to draw this pattern:

```
1 2 3 4 0
1 2 3 0 5
1 2 0 4 5
1 0 3 4 5
```

I got this pattern instead:

```
1 2 3 0 5
1 2 0 4 5
1 0 3 4 5
0 2 3 4 5
```

The program is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {


for (int i = 4 ; i >= 1; i--){
    for (int j = 1; j <=5 ; j++){
            if (i==j)
                cout <<"0";
            else
            cout <<j;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

What should I do to fix this, and print the expected pattern?

Comment: `std::cout << "1 2 3 4 0\n1 2 3 0 5\n1 2 0 4 5\n1 0 3 4 5";`

Comment: @DavidMakogon Well, the question contains the actual, and expected output.

Comment: for the sake of your own sanity: let your loops go from `0` to `n` such that `i,j` refers to the position you are currently printing. With the code as is, it is hard to figure out what `i` and `j` are actually refering to

Comment: actually not my buisness, but I disagree with the close votes. The question does contain the necessary code, actual and desired output and a more or less clear problem statement.

Comment: @tobi303 not close flagger, and I agree with you, but I think it does demonstrate a lack of research effort (since it's a trivial debugging issue) which makes it downvote worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this  :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {


for (int i = 4 ; i >= 1; i--){
    for (int j = 1; j <=5 ; j++){
            if (i==j-1)
                cout <<"0";
            else
            cout <<j;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I just changed `i == j` to `i == j -1` so: 
 
j = 1 4 == 0  it will go to else and print 1 
j = 2 4 == 1  it will go to else and print 2 
j = 3 4 == 2  it will go to else and print 3 
j = 4 4 == 3  it will go to else and print 4 
here  it will print 0 
 
j = 5 4 == 4 if is true so it will print 0 and so on until the outer loop ends.

Comment: Fixing the code without explaining the error or the fix is makes for an incomplete answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I just changed j to j-1, if he understands i == j  of course he will understand i == j - 1

Comment: I do not need an explanation for this.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy Don't tell me, add it to the answer. If the answer doesn't require an explanation because it's a typo, the question should be closed for being a typo and not answered.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I edited it.

Comment: Use the remainder operator, `%`.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this is really a good example on how bugs in code should not be fixed. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need 0 to be in 5th then 4th, 3th and 2nd position, but `i` iterates from 4 to 1. Just change first loop:

```
for (int i = 5 ; i >= 2; i--){
```

so `i` iterates from 5 to 2 as you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
    for (int i = 0 ; i <4 ; i++){
        for (int j = 1 ; j <=5 ; j++){
            if (i==(5-j))
                cout <<"0";
            else
                cout <<j;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
12340
12305
12045
10345
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.